# Use theme from framework-res.apk

Tags: android, android-theme, android-framework

In my app I want to use a theme which is defined in the `framework-res.apk`. I decompiled an other which uses this theme and I found this in the styles.xml

```
<style name="DefaultSettingsTheme" parent="@com.sonyericsson.uxp:style/SEMCTheme">
    <item name="android:directionality">leftToRight</item>
</style>
```

If I try to use this in my app it comes to an error because eclipse does not know that this theme is aviable in an other apk. How can I use this theme without rebuilding it?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't do this. But even if you could, I wouldn't advise you to do it since this would crash non-sony[ericsson]phones, because this theme is just included in the framework of sony[ericsson] devices. I would rather advise you to rebuild it :)

Comment: Okay thanks. Then an other question: Is it possible to get the background images which is used by the settings.apk programmatically? Some custom ROMs use other background images for the settings. Can I get this image?

Comment: Oh, sorry I was wrong. I totally forgot about [`Resources#getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). With this you can access resources from other apps. So even styles (and the background image you want from the settings apk). You can just check if the returned id is null or not(and set the theme programmatically with `setTheme()` depending on the result). If it's null then finding the resource failed and you can fallback to an other solution.

Comment: Oh great thanks. I'm not sure now what I have to give as parameter to the function. From the code above can you tell me whcih parameters I have to post to the method? `setTheme(getResources().getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage));`

Comment: Added an example. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but hope it works:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String packageName = ""; // package name of the app of which you want to access the resources;
        String resourceName = ""; // name of the resource you want to access
        int theme = 0;

        theme = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "style", packageName);

        if (theme != 0) {

            setTheme(theme);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
}
```